# J2EE -- Handling HttpSession session timouts while serving flash content

Tags: java, servlets, session-timeout

While serving flash based training material users peroidically experience a HttpSession session timeout.  Currently the inactivity timeout is set to default (30mins).

Questions:

1. Would it be a good idea to attempt to increase MaxInactiveInterval for any user who is requesting a training flash video to prevent the timeouts?
2. Would a better approach be to use a servlet lifecycle listener to re-activate the HttpSession if the HttpSession is associated with viewing training content? -- this may allow for more precise control over when the HttpSession object is going to timeout.
3. Only a small percentage of user's will actually be viewing this material at any one time, is there a performance penalty that should be considered for doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Rather fire ajax polls in the background.

Here's an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) with a little help of [jQuery](http://jquery.com). Just copy'n'paste'n'run it (and change the flash object to suit your actual code).

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>SO question 2290101</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                setInterval(function() {
                    $.get('poll');
                }, ${(pageContext.session.maxInactiveInterval - 10) * 1000});
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" ... >
            ...
        </object>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here [`${pageContext.session.maxInactiveInterval}`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getMaxInactiveInterval%28%29) returns the remnant of seconds the session has yet to live (and is been a tad shortened -just to be in time with poll- and converted to milliseconds so that it suits what [`setInterval()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) expects). The `$.get('poll')` should call a servlet which is mapped on an `url-pattern` of `/poll` and contains basically the following line in the `doGet()` method.

```
request.getSession(); // Keep session alive.
```

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

Is the flash video embedded in an HTML page?  If so, perhaps you could have an AJAX call on the page that periodically sends a "heartbeat" to the server to keep the session alive.